# What rule have I used to split the alphabet?

Tags: pattern, english

I've split the 26 letters (actually 25 letters) of the English language into two groups using a particular rule. Can you say what is the rule that I've used?

- First Group: **A D E F G H K L M N O Z**
- Second Group:**B C I J P Q R S T U V X Y**

Note that I've excluded **W** from both the groups as it fits partially into both the groups. Also,the font and the **BOLD** style doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I think it is, I'm not fully convinced myself though.

> There are commonly used words in English that are pronounced the same way as the letters in the second group. But with that logic H & R would be certainly in the second group.

Comment: You are right! Oops,**R** was supposed to be in the second group...But what's with **H**?

Comment: @CoolGuy Shouldn't J and O be in the second group and S be in the first group?

Comment: @randal'thor , Edited the [**J**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay)

Comment: @randal'thor , If **O** were in the Second Group,then **A** would be there too. Besides,**O** is not a word. I had doubts on **S** whether to put it in the first or the second group. I ended up putting **S** on in the second group.

Comment: @CoolGuy I'd say 'oh' and even 'O' are words, but I realise you have to draw the line somewhere, otherwise 'ee' and 'eff' and 'gee' would all slip down to the second group!

Comment: @CoolGuy Its just that H is pronounced as "etch" where I live

Comment: Oh is definitely a real word pronounced like o, and should be in the second group. h is pronounced aitch, not etch, and should not. Ee, eff and gee are not actual words so I don't see any blurred lines

Comment: Why are S and V in the second group?  -1'ed the question because of all this.

Comment: a, bee, see, (dee), (ee), eff, gee, (aitch), eye, jay, 'kay, (ell), em, en, oh, pee, cue, are, (ess), tee, you, (vee), double-you, ex, why, (zed).

Comment: An ell is 45 inches (in England; other countries vary), and L should thus be in the second group.

Comment: Per dictionary.com, to "gee" an animal is to urge it on (17th century; origin unknown).  Dictionary.com also gives a pronunciation of "cay" (a small island) that matches the letter "K".